# firebase `signInWithEmailAndPassword` undefined

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm a little new to firebase/cloud functions so forgive if I'm missing something simple.

I'm frustrated now because what I see on the documentation is not working. I read this part of the documentation: [signInWithEmailAndPassword](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html?authuser=0#signInWithEmailAndPassword) but when I use it in my nodejs code that I deploy to Firebase Cloud functions I get the error:

> TypeError: auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword is not a function

Note that `auth` is actually `auth()`, I just decided to store the result of `auth()` in the variable `auth`, so don't let it confuse you.

I looked at the documentation and I don't see anything wrong I'm doing. This post [Firebase Auth On The Server With Node.JS / Express](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/KzW7eAfjV5k) and got this for it

> If you initialize the Node.js SDK with an API key instead of a service account, you can use the normal client-side auth methods like authWithEmailAndPassword()

Currently I initialize it like this:

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)
```

What exactly am I expected to change so that the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method becomes available on the object?

Do I really need to get a API key and initialize it like I'm initializing a frontend project when I'm using `firebase-admin` on a nodejs server?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions run on a trusted environment, and is using the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to access Firebase services. There is no way (nor usually a need) to sign in as a user with email+password using the Admin SDK.

The Firebase Admin SDK runs with administrative privileges, giving it already has full access to the entire Firebase project that the code runs in.